# How to change BackColor of multiple Textboxes depending on the Text-property

Tags: vb.net

I want to reduce this code as much as possible. I have about 8 textboxes and I take a lot of time, `txtDrawA1` to `txtDraw8`. I want to change the textbox color more easily, depending on the following values, 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 - each value is assigned the same color.

```
Private Sub txtDrawA1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDrawA1.TextChanged
     If txtDrawA1.Text = ("1") Then
         txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.Red
     ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("2") Then
         txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.Aqua
     ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("3") Then
         txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.Chocolate
     ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("4") Then
         txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond
     ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("5") Then
        txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood
     ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("6") Then
        txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
     ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("7") Then
        txtDrawA1.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
     End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtDrawA2_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtDrawA2.TextChanged
    If txtDrawA2.Text = ("1") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("2") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.Aqua
    ElseIf txtDrawA2.Text = ("3") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.Chocolate
    ElseIf txtDrawA2.Text = ("4") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond
    ElseIf txtDrawA2.Text = ("5") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood
    ElseIf txtDrawA2.Text = ("6") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
    ElseIf txtDrawA1.Text = ("7") Then
        txtDrawA2.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code in a sub and use one sub to handle multiple events from your different text boxes.

```
Private Sub txtDrawA1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
                                  System.EventArgs) Handles txtDrawA1.TextChanged,
                                                            txtDrawA2.TextChanged,
                                                            txtDrawA3.TextChanged
'I just did three you can add as many as you like make sure that you select the correct event

        SetColor(sender)
    End Sub

   Public Sub SetColor(txtBox As TextBox)
        If txtBox.Text = ("1") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf txtBox.Text = ("2") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        ElseIf txtBox.Text = ("3") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.Chocolate
        ElseIf txtBox.Text = ("4") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond
        ElseIf txtBox.Text = ("5") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood
        ElseIf txtBox.Text = ("6") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        ElseIf txtBox.Text = ("7") Then
            txtBox.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows, for example.

Create one method which handles the `TextChanged`-event of the eight textboxes and call the second method each time to set the appropriate color.
I also added a `Case Else` as you may want to reset the backcolor to the default when the textbox contains another value.

```
Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtDrawA1.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA2.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA3.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA4.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA5.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA6.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA7.TextChanged,
                                                                            txtDrawA8.TextChanged
    SetTextBoxColor(DirectCast(sender, TextBox))
End Sub

Sub SetTextBoxColor(txt As TextBox)
    Select Case txt.Text
        Case "1"
            txt.BackColor = Color.Red
        Case "2"
            txt.BackColor = Color.Aqua
        Case "3"
            txt.BackColor = Color.Chocolate
        Case "4"
            txt.BackColor = Color.BlanchedAlmond
        Case "5"
            txt.BackColor = Color.BurlyWood
        Case "6"
            txt.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet
        Case "7"
            txt.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue
        Case Else
            txt.BackColor = SystemColors.Window
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks for all :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing a specialized class that holds all the Color mappings in a [`Dictionary(Of string, Color)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary%602);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2), which exposes a method to retrive a Color based on a string value, used as the Dictionary Key.

The **`TextBoxColors`** Class **`GetColor()`** method returns a Color if the `Key`, corresponding to the current `TextBox.Text`, is defined. Otherwise, it returns `Color.White`.

The Event Handlers are all added, in the `Form.Load()` event, to all the TextBoxes which have a Name that matches a *pattern*: **`"txtDraw"`**, here.
You could instead use the Tag property, setting it to a specific value in all the TextBoxes that need to be included in this selection.

Note that I'm supposing that all TextBoxes are child of the Form. If they are child o some other Container, just change the `Me` reference in `For Each txtDraw As TextBox In Me.Controls` to the actual Parent.

[image: Color Table to TextBox BackColor]

**Edit**:
Since your using Visual Studio 2008, the Lambda in the `AddHandler` statement is not supported. Code modified to comply with the (very old) VB.Net version. You need a reference to `System. Linq` and the Framework version must be 3.5 or newer (to support the `OfType` and `Where` extensions).

```
Public Class TextBoxColors
    Private ColorTable As Dictionary(Of String, Color) = New Dictionary(Of String, Color)()
    Public Sub New()
        ColorTable.Add("1", Color.Red)
        ColorTable.Add("2", Color.Aqua)
        ColorTable.Add("3", Color.Chocolate)
        ColorTable.Add("4", Color.BlanchedAlmond)
        ColorTable.Add("5", Color.BurlyWood)
        ColorTable.Add("6", Color.BlueViolet)
        ColorTable.Add("7", Color.DarkBlue)
    End Sub
    Public Function GetColor(ColorMap As String) As Color
        Return If(ColorTable.Keys.Contains(ColorMap), ColorTable(ColorMap), Color.White)
    End Function
End Class

Private txtColor As TextBoxColors = New TextBoxColors()

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For Each txtDraw As TextBox In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox).Where(Function(txt) txt.Name.StartsWith("txtDraw"))
        AddHandler txtDraw.TextChanged, AddressOf Me.txtDraw_TextChanged
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub txtDraw_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim txtDraw As TextBox = CType(sender, TextBox)
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDraw.Text) Then
        txtDraw.BackColor = txtColor.GetColor(txtDraw.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This site isn't really for code optimization - it belongs more on http://codereview.stackexhange.com This site is more for answering specific problems with code that doesn't work. Cheers

Comment: Not worked. this code

Comment: Yes, it does. The *animation* you see is produced using this exact code. You implemented it the wrong way or your TextBoxes names do not  begin with `txtDraw`. If you explain what is not working, I can help you fix it.

Comment: Right, it doesn't matter. I've seen your other question, where you posted this code asking why you have an error in the `AddHandler` statement. You're using Visual Studio 2008. This kind of Lambda is not supported. You'll have to implement the handler in a more different way. I'll make an edit. If you're using such an old version of VB.Net, this should be included in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not know, I'll specify from now on ... or I'll migrate to the newer one, but I'm afraid the project will not be in trouble if I'm migrating to a new version.

Comment: No problem, I'll adapt the code. Wait a minute.

Comment: OK, code updated. Try now. (I'm not sure what was supported by that VB.Net version, but IMO it should work).